FlatMap vs Reduce for extracting data from a nested object
I have a dataset as such, where there may be multiple testResults array elements, along with there being 1 or many response array elements; and I an wanting to extract all of the potential completionDate values into their own array.
const testResults = [
  {
    "value": {
      "data": {
        "response": [
          {
            "completionDate": "2024-10-10T17:44:00",
          },
          {
            "completionDate": "2024-10-11T17:44:00",
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  ...
];

I'm curious about the most effective/efficient way in which this could be done that is also readable by the rest of my team.
I have plenty of experience with using map and flatMap for things like this but have recently being using reduce more and wonder if one is more advantageous over the other, and if there's any other method I have not considered.
flatMap
const timestamps = testResults.flatMap(result => 
  result.value.data.response.map(check => check?.completionDate)
);

reduce
const timestamps = testResults.reduce((acc, res) => {
  res.value.data.response.forEach(check => {
    acc.push(check.completionDate);
  });
  return acc;
}, []);

I did put use console.time around each of them and found that

map: 0.103ms
reduce: 0.067ms

Does this really indicate that the reduce is that much more efficient?

In general, avoid using .reduce() when there is a more specialised alternative of it. Like here. .reduce() is more of a toolbox to create other solutions. .map(), .filter(), .flatMap() and the like can all be represented as a reduce operation but .map() and .filter() and .flatMap() and the like are more direct in the intention you present to others.

"Does this really indicate that the reduce is that much more efficient?" I doubt you can derive much of a meaning from these results. You've apparently tested a single call to these. With a single dataset. On a single environment. On a single version of that environment. I doubt the number tells you anything meaningful.

Yes, reduce() is a king and usually faster than any other methods that create intermediate arrays.
Also I expect that flatMap() uses iterators that are notoriously slower 6.2 times exactly in the Chrome. And the first test with 10 child array items shows exactly that.
` Chrome/130
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>                 n=1        |       n=10        |       n=100       |      n=1000     
reduce()    ■ 1.00x x10m 240 | ■ 1.00x   x1m 260 | ■ 1.00x x100k 269 | ■ 1.00x x10k 254
flatMap()     6.21x  x1m 149 |   3.92x x100k 102 |   3.54x x100k 951 |   3.66x x10k 930
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- `

Open in the playground


const $chunk = () => [{"value": {
      "data": {
        "response": Array.from({length: 10}, () => ({completionDate: new Date}))
      }
  }}];
const $input = [];

// @benchmark flatMap()
$input.flatMap(result => 
  result.value.data.response.map(check => check?.completionDate)
);

// @benchmark reduce()
$input.reduce((acc, result) => {
  result.value.data.response.forEach(check => {
    acc.push(check.completionDate);
  });
  return acc;
}, []);

/*@skip*/ fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js').then(r => r.text().then(eval));



